# Azure routing and DNS

Tags: azure, dns

If I want, I could buy a new domain and point to `something.azurewebsites.net`. No Registrar imposes a barrier here...
My question is:

- will it work? or the owner of `something.azurewebsites.net` has to explicitally do some configuration?
- What if I point to the current IP (or the now possible, fixed IP) of `something.azurewebsites.net`?

Details:

- I don't own a domain neither want to buy one just for testing this, or i would...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/ should answer your question.  In short, yes, the owner of something.azurewebsites.net has to setup a verification entry in the Azure management portal.